# Get the href of the next page of the current page

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a template associated with multiple pages.
I have the nodes with different properties including href.
On the current page I want to display the href of the next page for every page that I visit.
Actuatly I select manually href but in this way the address remains the same for all pages.

```
<h1>
    <xsl:value-of select="/content/component[@type='navigation']
                          /navigation[@type='tree']
                          /page/page/following::page/following::page
                          /following::page/page/page/following::page/@label"/>
</h1>
```

How do I get the href next to each page?
My idea was to create an array with all the href and do a for-each to scroll through the list and let me return the href next position.
It  be the right solution? as you implement?

Comment: Please show us a small but representative XML input sample. And we need to see enough code to understand the context in XSLT, for instance, a template with its `match` pattern.

Comment: The structure that I considered is at the following link: http://sviluppo.unibas.it/site/home/ateneo/questionario/sezione-f.html?xml=1   I build the section, press the button "Invia" and see the link of the next section.